# Error when uploading image to android

Tags: android, json, image, upload, base64

I'm trying to upload an image from android to server use JSON+Base64.That's work when I used an emulator.But when I used my phone, my image is lost..please help

I can not post image, please see image here:http://i.upanh.com/rtnezb and
http://i.upanh.com/rtneqi

And this's my code:

```
photo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nocamera);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();       
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);   
imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
ImageBase64=Base64.encodeBytes(imageupdate);
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you mean by "lost"? If you mean it failed to upload, that could be for any number of reasons. Is there any logcat output? Any exceptions being thrown? The best way to figure out a problem on a phone is to debug it on a phone. Plug the phone into the computer using USB, set the phone to developer mode (in settings), and it should appear as a target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Mutipart entity to upload the image file. Yo must download "httpmime-4.2.3.jar" library, here is a sample code from one of my projects that works perfect. I hope that can help you.

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    InputStream is = null;
    String json = "";
    JSONObject jObj;

    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        File img = new File("local_image_path_here");
        entity.addPart("param_name_here", new FileBody(img));

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```